# rails - printing text using iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying tp print a non updateable value in my  page. 
So far it displays

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |builder| %>
 <fieldset>
    <%= builder.text_area :name %>
 </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

which works and I need it to display a non updatable - plain text. So I tried to do

Option 1

```
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |builder| %>
 <fieldset>
    <%= builder.label :name, "Ingredients" %>
 </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

But no success. this does work: 
option 2

```
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
   <td><%= ingredient.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

What is the main difference between option 1 and 2  ? I prefer using option 1 with the `<li>` tag. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The main difference is the HTML produced. I don't understand your comment about "option 1 with the `li` tag, since that isn't what option 1 does, and it's not clear what you've tried in that regard

Comment: I am trying to pring all the list of ingredients. I have successully printed them in a test area (following a rails cast) but I have troubles making the a regular text

Answer (score 1):

Label is used to create a label for a field, and not meant to show its value. Option 2 is exactly how you would display the contents of the name field. Option 1 style of formatting is to show the literal 'Ingredients' instead of 'name'. Ususally, that would be followed by `<%= builder.text_area :name %>`.

Another possible inconsistency: @recipe.ingredients is an array, so there is no field called ingredients.name. As a test, try ingredients[0].name.

So in option 1, try:

```
<% ingredient = @recipe.ingredients[0] %>
<%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |builder| %>
 <fieldset>
    <%= builder.label :name, "Ingredients" %>
 </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

If that printed the label 'Ingredients', then you could print the list of ingredients with:

```
<td>Ingredients:</td>
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
   <td><%= ingredient.name %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It just prints the word ingredient - not the name(value) of the ingredient. What I need is to print something like  <% ingredient = @recipe.ingredients[i] %>